# Linear Fractional Transforms maps the upper half unit disc onto the first quadrant

Tags: complex-analysis

Since the LFT（Linear Fractional Transform）preserves the angles, and since $\{|z|=1,\operatorname{Im} z>0\}$ intersects $[-1,1]$ at $-1$ and $1$. So we must map one of the two right angles to the right angle form by the real and imaginary axes. Then, my question is: **where does the other right angle go? Can we say that the real axis and imaginary axis intersects orthogonally at $\infty$?**

Comment: There is not just one LFT, there are many. Unless you can tell us which of the many LFTs you are referring to, your question does not make much sense.

Comment: @LeeMosher:I think there are two such LFTs, $T(z)=k(1+z)/(1-z),k>0$ and $T(z)=ih(1-z)/(1+z),h>0$. If you wanna me choose one, I wanna say: Both. ：）

Comment: @LeeMosher: I feel ashamed for asking this question. I should read my textbook more carefully. The point here is that LFT preserve angles on the whole complex plane except one possible point. The upper half disc has two right angles on the boundary, then one of them must be map to the origin. Say, $z=-1$, then $z=1$ must be map to $\infty$, and then the LFT is not analytic at $z=1$. So, there is no such an "angle preserving" at $z=1$. And hence my question does not make sense. I hope I get the point.

Comment: An LFT can be considered as an automorphism of Riemann sphere, i.e. it is defined anywhere as a map ℂP¹ → ℂP¹. Then, angles are preserved anywhere without exceptions, and yes, real and imaginary axes intersect orthogonally at ∞. BTW could anybody review the answer http://math.stackexchange.com/a/921667/168952 ? Some silent hater of differential geometry ⇩ed it ☹