# Why is it that linear fractional transformations cannot take the upper half-plane to the first quadrant?

Tags: complex-analysis, analysis

> **Problem:** Is there a linear fractional transformation that takes the upper half-plane to the first quadrant?  If yes, write it down.  If no, give proof.

**Attempt:**

1. We have that a linear fractional transformation $f$ is a transformation of form

   $$
   f(z) = {az + b \over cz + d} \text{ s.t. } ad - bc \ne 0
   $$

   and where $a,b,c,d \in \mathbb{C}$.
2. Note by another theorem, $f$ must send circles and lines to circles or lines.
3. I **think** (but am not certain) that linear fractional transformations must take boundaries to boundaries.
4. Hence if the supposition were true, we would have that the $x$-axis of $\mathbb{C}$ is sent to the boundary of the first quandrant (i.e., the union of the positive reals, zero, and the pure imaginary numbers from $0$ upwards).  This violates (2).
5. Then the argument is complete.

Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, it's correct. Point 3. follows because Möbius transformations are biholomorphisms (in particular homeomorphisms) of the entire Riemann sphere.

Comment: Could you just add a few details. By the "upper half plane", do you mean the open one $\{x + y\mathrm{i} : y > 0\}$ or the closed one $\{x + y\mathrm{i} : y \ge 0\}$? Are you considering only the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, or the extended complex plane $\hat{\mathbb{C}} = \mathbb{C} \cup \{\infty\}$. When you talk about the quadrant, is it open $\{x + y\mathrm{i} : x>0, y > 0\}$ or closed $\{x + y\mathrm{i} : x \ge 0, y \ge 0\}$

Comment: Unfortunately, those details aren't specified on my end.  I'm assuming that my professor is assuming that the upper half plane and first quadrant is open, and that we are working in $\mathbb{C}$ and not the extended complex plane.

Comment: $\sqrt{z}$ takes the first quadrant into a half plane.

Comment: While leaving 0,1,infinity fixed. Which LFTs leave these three points fixed? Are the mappings equivalent.

Comment: Maybe only z , and $\sqrt{z}$ isn't z.

Answer (score -1):

No. Linear fractional transformations naturally act on the Riemann sphere ℂP<sup>1</sup> by biholomorphisms. (In fact, *all* biholomorphisms of ℂP<sup>1</sup> are linear fractional transformations, but we don’t need it.) A biholomorphism, i.e. a holomorphic map with holomorphic inverse, is also a diffeomorphism: any Riemannian surface is also a smooth 2-dimensional real manifold.

A half-plane on ℂ is a half of Riemann sphere bounded by a great circle. Its boundary is smooth. The boundary of a quadrant isn’t smooth.

This was a conceptual proof that used “higher mathematics”, but I’m sure one can also present an elementary proof.